# Grub shows Forcepae not found, OS hangs while booting

Tags: grub2, acpi

I just installed LXLE on a computer. In a previous post, I was told how to get Lubuntu to work using `Forcepae` and `acpi_backlight=vendor`. Usually those flags are copied when I install, but LXLE didn't copy them. I tried to add `acpi_backlight=vendor` and `Forcepae` to the commands list, but grub spits out an error saying that the command `Forcepae` was not found. Then the boot hangs at a line that says

```
[Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
```

This is a secondary computer, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!